# lodash.fp.convert.words not working as expected

Tags: lodash

Am I using lodash.fp's `convert` method incorrectly? It seems like it doesn't work in the case of `words`

```
const fp = require('lodash/fp')
const assert = require('assert')

const words = fp.words.convert({ cap: false })

assert.equal(typeof words, 'function') // true as expected

// here I'd expect `words` to return a function that is expecting the
// remaining string argument
const splitByX = words(/[^x]+/g)

assert.equal(typeof splitByX, 'function')
```

published the above snippet here: https://runkit.com/lokua/lodash-fp-words-bug

I've also tried using `fixed: false` in the call to `convert` but get the exact same results.

This appears to be a bug to me, but I thought it better to post on StackOverflow before submitting a report in case my understanding of how convert works is off.

Here is a link to related issue asking how fp.words works, the answer was to use convert: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3397

using lodash@4.17.4